# Difference between vbHidden and Windows.Visibility.Hidden in WPF vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, wpf-4.5

What is the main difference between vbHidden and Windows.Visibility.Hidden ?
**vbHidden**

```
 Private Sub btnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim Ct As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Ct.Visibility = vbHidden       


End Sub
```

**Windows.Visibility.Hidden**

```
 Private Sub btnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim Ct As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Ct.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden


End Sub
```

Comment: vbHidden is a file attribute and Hidden is a Visibility property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**vbHidden**

- Indicates that the file is a hidden file for file-access functions.
- **Namespace:**  Microsoft.VisualBasic
- **Assembly:**  Microsoft.VisualBasic (in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll)
- **Declaration** : `Public Const vbHidden As FileAttribute`
- When you call the **Dir, GetAttr, or SetAttr functions,** you can use the **FileAttribute enumeration** in your code in place of the actual values.
- The Attributes argument takes the *FileAttribute* enumeration members.
- When performing file I/O operations, the `My.Computer.FileSystem` object provides greater performance and ease of use than legacy file I/O methods.

**Windows.Visibility.Hidden**

- Specifies the **display state of an element**.
- **Namespace:**  System.Windows
- **Assembly:**  PresentationCore (in PresentationCore.dll)
- **Declaration:**Public Enumeration Visibility.
- Elements that have a Visibility value of Collapsed do not occupy any layout space. By default, elements are Visible.

  **---MEMBERS---**
- **Collapsed:**   Do not display the element, and do not reserve space for it in layout.
- **Hidden:**  Do not display the element, but reserve space for the element in layout.
- **Visible:** Display the element.